# Finding value in a matrix using python

Tags: python, methods

I am getting the error 'int object is not iterable' on this method in my class. Someone assist me find the bug as I can't see what I am doing wrong

```
def find(self, val): #finds value in matrix
    if 0 <= val <= 8:
        for i,j in range(3):
            #for j in range(3):
            if self.matrix[i][j] == val:
               return i, j
    return None
```

Comment: What do you expect `for i,j in range(3)` does?

Comment: Why did you comment out `for j in range(3):`

Comment: I previously had 'for i in range(3): for j in range(3):' This was giving a class does not have __getitem__ error

Comment: @MailerDaemon then your problem is somewhere else in your code and you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I think your problem is in `self.matrix` (besides the `i, j` thing which is wrong). Tells you that int is not iterable because you cant unpack an int into two variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
def find(self, val):  # finds value in matrix
if 0 <= val <= 8:
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if self[i][j] == val:
                return i, j
return None
```

Example:

```
self = [[2,1,2],[1,6,4],[0,0,2]]
val = 4

i, j = find(self, val)

print(i)
print(j)
```

Print: 
1 
2

If define self as matrix of numpy:

```
def find(self, val):  # finds value in matrix
    if 0 <= val <= 8:
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if self.item((i, j)) == val:
                    return i, j
    return None
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist. When I change to the above I am getting `class instance has no attribute '__getitem__' `

Comment: @MailerDaemon as long as you dont say what matrix is, we cant help you. Here Manuel is supposing you subclassed any kind of subscriptable object. Or you made your own.

Comment: `class State:
    def __init__(self, matrix, moves = 0):
        self.matrix = matrix #matrix of values
        self.moves = moves #total moves up to this point `

Comment: I dont use ".matrix", I used lists

Answer (score 0):

here is the part of your code that is causing the error

```
for i,j in range(3)
```

the python's built-in range function generates a sequence of number that are then assigned to one variable, but you're using two variables instead
. This is how your code should be :

```
def find(self, val): #finds value in matrix
    if 0 <= val <= 8:
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if self.matrix[i][j] == val:
                    return i, j
    return None
```